# Why are Mapping Cylinders of “nice” functions CW Complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I keep running across comments and answers to questions that imply that the mapping cylinder for “nice” functions is a CW complex.  Why is this necessarily so?

Consider any function $ f \colon X \to Y $.  Using Hatcher’s (p2) standard definition, the mapping cylinder will not be a CW complex unless Y, the range of f, is a CW complex.

If f is a nice function, its image may be nice, but the rest of Y can be almost anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe they're defining "nice" to mean "whatever I need for the mapping cylinder to be a CW complex."

Comment: When people say *is* a CW complex they normally mean *is homeomorphic to a CW complex*, or more frequently *is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex*. For example Hatcher's definition does not give you an actual CW complex unless both $X,Y$ are CW complexes and $f$ is cellular. On the other hand, as you point out, the mapping cylinder is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex if and only if $Y$ is.

Comment: You should make precise what "nice" means. In the present form it could be anything and an answer is impossible.

Comment: @Tyrone If being a CW-complex means "homotopy equivalent to a CW complex", then as you say everything is trivial because the mapping cylinder is homotopy equivalent to its base. I cannot imagine that this is the intended interpretation.

Comment: @Paul & @ Qiaochu - It doesn’t really matter how you define nice, because in every case you have to look at at the structure of Y as well. But, for example, f(x)=c , a constant.  How can we say anything about the structure of the mapping cylinder even In this case?

Comment: The mapping cylinder contains both $X,Y$ as a closed subspaces, so if they are not both at least, say, perfectly normal hereditarily paracompact Hausdorff spaces, then $M_f$ cannot be a CW complex, or even homeomorphic to one, regardless of how 'nice' $f$ might be. If $X,Y$ are CW complexes, then as I said above, 'nice' should mean 'skeletal'. If you want $M_f$ to be an actual CW complex then there aren't any weaker assumptions on $f$ you can make.